# How to validate a form from a config.jelly on Jenkins?

Tags: java, validation, plugins, jenkins, jelly

I can do it from a global.jelly file, but it doesn't work from a config.jelly.
Here is the procedure for a global.jelly file:

#### Jelly:

```
<f:entry title="Value" field="value">
    <f:textbox />
</f:entry>
```

---

#### JAVA:

```
public static final class Descriptor extends BuildStepDescriptor<Builder>{

    //descriptor's code

    /**
     * Performs on-the-fly validation of the form field 'value'.
     * 
     * @param value
     *            This parameter receives the value that the user has typed.
     * @return Indicates the outcome of the validation. This is sent to the
     *         browser.
     */
    public FormValidation doCheckValue(@QueryParameter String value) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(value.isEmpty()) {
            return FormValidation.warning("You must fill this box!");
        }
        return FormValidation.ok();
    }
}
```

This doesn't apply anymore when the jelly code is placed in a configuration file (config.jelly), no matter whether the `doCheckValue` method is placed in the plugin class or in its descriptor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what it becomes with a config.jelly file. The `textbox` takes one addional attribute : `checkUrl`.

#### Jelly:

```
<f:entry title="Value" field="value">
    <f:textbox 
        checkUrl="'descriptorByName/NAME_OF_YOUR_JAVA_CLASS/checkValue?value='+escape(this.value)" />
</f:entry>
```

*Note: `this.value` is specific to Javascript. It gets the **value** of your `value` variable. Don't touch it.*

The **Java** code remains the same.

Comment: I have a question. Where should I put <NAME_OF_YOUR_JAVA_CLASS> class? I've followed instruction for validating text-field in my plugin, but I see "HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /job/jenkins-plugin-test/descriptorByName/TextBoxValueValidationDescriptor/checkValue. Reason:Not Found Powered by Jetty://" What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Be careful, Jetty is not the same as Jelly. Are you implementing this as part of a Jenkins plugin?

Comment: Yes, I have working Jenkins plugin. I want to add validation of text field to config.jelly

Comment: I guess `NAME_OF_YOUR_JAVA_CLASS` actually needs to be the fully qualified name, i.e. including the package name.